# How do I make a custom button dynamic across objects?

Tags: visualforce, custom, button

I want the child Work Order Line Item object to inherit the record type from its parent Work Order.  This will allow me to show a different page layout for the child that matches the parent.  There are multiple pairs of WO and WOLI. At the moment I have it hard coded like this:

```
/a0k/e?CF00N11000000MEYb={!Work_Order__c.Name}& CF00N11000000MEYb_lkid={!Work_Order__c.Id}& retURL=/{!Work_Order__c.Id}& RecordType=01211000000CvvX
```

but would like to make it dynamic so which ever parent record type is in use the child will always be created with the correct record type as well.

Comment: Here is an old blog post on the subject that may help [Automatically setting the record type of a detail object based on the record type of its master object](http://force201.wordpress.com/2011/05/21/automatically-setting-the-record-type-of-a-detail-object-based-on-the-record-type-of-its-master-object/).

Answer (score 2):

You can create a formula field on the object to capture the record type of parent work order. Lets call it ParentRecordType.

You enter the formula as `Parent.RecordTypeId`.

Now, you can initialize your button as

```
/a0k/e?CF00N11000000MEYb={!Work_Order__c.Name}& CF00N11000000MEYb_lkid={!Work_Order__c.Id}& retURL=/{!Work_Order__c.Id}& RecordType={!Work_Order__c.ParentRecordType}
```